# Userena with multiple signup forms (form wizard)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I'm trying to setup multiple forms to [django-userena](http://www.django-userena.org/) signup.

So from [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) i can do it like this:

**forms.py:**

```
class Form1(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()

class Form2(forms.Form):
    some_field_2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**views.py:**

```
class Wizard(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return render_to_response('done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

**urls.py:**

```
(r'^signup/$', Wizard.as_view([Form1, Form2])),
```

And it would be like a one form, placed on two pages with "next" and "previous" buttons.

---

But userena code has some differences, it should be like this:

**views.py:**

```
if userena_settings.USERENA_WITHOUT_USERNAMES and (signup_form == SignupForm):
    signup_form = SignupFormOnlyEmail

form = signup_form()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = signup_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()

        # Send the signup complete signal
        userena_signals.signup_complete.send(sender=None,
                                             user=user)


        if success_url: redirect_to = success_url
        else: redirect_to = reverse('userena_signup_complete',
                                    kwargs={'username': user.username})

        # A new signed user should logout the old one.
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            logout(request)
        return redirect(redirect_to)

if not extra_context: extra_context = dict()
extra_context['form'] = form
return ExtraContextTemplateView.as_view(template_name=template_name,
                                        extra_context=extra_context)(request)
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^accounts/signup/$', 'userena.views.signup', {'signup_form': SignupFormExtra}),
```

So my great problem here - to integrate this two things, but I don't even know from what should I begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the better idea will be using something like this http://wbotelhos.com/stepy and show your forms on single page?

Comment: Thank you, used this plugin for my project, that's much easier!